EF Core 8 : single value objects. Error on linq
In EF Core 8, I'm trying to do this query (Active is a simple value object of type bool):
return await _dbSet
                .Where(e => e.Active.Value)
                .ToListAsync();

And I get:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(e
=> e.Active.Value)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Entity:
public abstract class StarSchemaEntity : Entity
{
    public Date Timestamp { get; set; } = new Date(DateTime.Now);
    public DatabaseBoolean Active { get; set; } = new DatabaseBoolean(true);
}


public partial class ExecutionEntity : StarSchemaEntity
{ 
    public Name Name { get; set; } = null!;
}

ModelBuilder:
modelBuilder.Entity<ExecutionEntity>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

    entity.ToTable("EXECUTIONS");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasConversion<DatabaseTableIdConverter>()
        .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
        .HasColumnName("Id");
    entity.Property(e => e.Active)
        .HasConversion<DatabaseBooleanConverter>()
        .HasMaxLength(1)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("'Y'")
        .IsFixedLength()
        .HasColumnName("ACTIVE");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .HasConversion<NameConverter>()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasColumnName("NAME");
    entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
        .HasConversion<DateConverter>()
        .HasPrecision(6)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ")
        .HasColumnName("TIMESTAMP");
}); 

Converter:
public class DatabaseBooleanConverter : ValueConverter<DatabaseBoolean, string>
{
    public DatabaseBooleanConverter() : base
    (
        v => v.Value.ToString(),
        v => new DatabaseBoolean(v, true))
    { }
}

How could I do a linq operation using value objects?

Show class and mapping. You have shown code which should work if Active is bool? and correctly mapped to database.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv is correctly mapped to the database and the bool values cannot be null, by default is true

How do you expect answer if we do not see anything, except correct query?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I know it works because without the "where" works correctly, nevertheless i updated the question

Well, now i see your problem. Properties with conversion CANNOT be used in LINQ Queries.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv and is there a way to be able to use value objects and linq?

Check this answer, ugly but should work. If you have experience in Expression Trees, it is possible to create interceptor and correct Expression Tree, to make such (bool)(object)x conversions automatically.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv if not the best solution will be to have a primitive value entity and then map it to the entity with value objects?

Sorry, i do not follow what you mean. You can map to database simple bool property , which can be used in LINQ Queries, for DDD create another property not mapped to database - cannot be used in LINQ queries.

But EF8, it was supposed to solve the DDD problems, right??

I don't think so, check github issue

@marcosagni98 there's no DDD problem. A lot of people misunderstand what DDD is about and try to (incorrectly) apply what they assume it says about domain entities to database entities. DDD doesn't say you have to create your own DatabaseBoolean class and creating a class named Date when DateOnly is available is just begging for trouble. The very fact you had to add Database to what should be a domain property is a pretty strong indicator that something's wrong

@marcosagni98 DatabaseBooleanConverter tells EF how to convert values to/from DatabaseBoolean. It doesn't tell it how to map it to SQL expressions. That's not anything that application code can do anyway. PostgreSQL may be the only database that has a true boolean type. Most databases use bit for this and require expressions like Active = 1. You can't express that in a value converter

@marcosagni98 and finally, if Active is meant to implement soft-deletes, it's anti-DDD because it's an implementation detail. First of all, businesses don't use soft deletes, they use compensating transactions. Second, views can be used to return only "active" records, or temporal tables (where available) can be used to show the "current" and "previous" versions of data. EF global filters could also be used to only return "active" rows, similar (but less powerful than) mapping to "active" views

Linq does not allow conversions.
To solve the error instead of comparing a value object value with a primitive value I compared the value object against a value object
var TrueValue = new DatabaseBoolean(true);
return await _dbSet
    .Where(e => (e.Active == TrueValue))
    .ToListAsync();

This solved the error
